# organizing items in array by first key value pair

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

**i am trying to organize the index of objects in an array by their first key/value**

i have an array objects that are not organized like they should be.

they have to be in order an so I can appropriately add their timers. you can see below they are unorganized and the timers are messed up.

I tried adding object keys but it complicated everything. thanks

```
var myObject = 
[ 
  { stepNumber: 2,
    sendTimeFromNow: 259200000 },
  { stepNumber: 1,    
    sendTimeFromNow: 259200000 }
]
```

Comment: If it's just a literal, rewrite the order so that it works. If it's dynamically constructed, show us the code that does that.

Comment: Have you tried `myObject.sort(appropriateComparisonFunction)`?

Comment: Just curious, did you try researching this before posting the question?

Comment: You might want to take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript

Comment: That is where I got my answer from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic array sorting should work.

```
myObject.sort((a, b) => {
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
});
```

In your case you will need to compare properties on a and b:

```
myObject.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.stepNumber < b.stepNumber ? -1 : a.stepNumber > b.stepNumber ? 1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: this works great! thnks

Answer (score 0):

Use sort.

Order by stepNumber (alternate a and b for ascending or descending order)

`myObject.sort((a, b) => a.stepNumber - b.stepNumber)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Array.sort`. Here is an example of it in action:

```
myObject.sort(function(a, b){
    var setNumberA = 123, //some number
        setNumberB = 4567; //some other number
    // Then just compare the 2 dates
    if(setNumberA < setNumberB) return -1;
    if(setNumberA > setNumberB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks zoe - helpful but not as much as ryans ;)

Comment: But does it deserve a down vote?